Failed to display Jupyter Widgets
I have installed Anaconda on my new laptop and I can't use the library ipywidgets any more. Just an example snippet of the code which I ran for test purposes -
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
w = widgets.IntSlider()
display(w)

I got the following Javascript error :
[Open Browser Console for more detailed log - Double click to close this message]
Failed to load model class 'IntSliderModel' from module '@jupyter-widgets/controls'
Error: Module @jupyter-widgets/controls, version ^1.5.0 is not registered, however,         2.0.0 is
    at f.loadClass (http://localhost:8889/lab/extensions/@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager/static/446.fdf8b1b233cb8c1783f6.js?v=fdf8b1b233cb8c1783f6:1:75041)
    at f.loadModelClass (http://localhost:8889/lab/extensions/@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager/static/327.68dbf8491690b3aff1e7.js?v=68dbf8491690b3aff1e7:1:10729)
    at f._make_model (http://localhost:8889/lab/extensions/@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager/static/327.68dbf8491690b3aff1e7.js?v=68dbf8491690b3aff1e7:1:7517)
    at f.new_model (http://localhost:8889/lab/extensions/@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager/static/327.68dbf8491690b3aff1e7.js?v=68dbf8491690b3aff1e7:1:5137)
    at f.handle_comm_open (http://localhost:8889/lab/extensions/@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager/static/327.68dbf8491690b3aff1e7.js?v=68dbf8491690b3aff1e7:1:3894)
    at _handleCommOpen (http://localhost:8889/lab/extensions/@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager/static/446.fdf8b1b233cb8c1783f6.js?v=fdf8b1b233cb8c1783f6:1:73457)
    at v._handleCommOpen (http://localhost:8889/static/notebook/3676.bundle.js:1:30808)
    at async v._handleMessage (http://localhost:8889/static/notebook/3676.bundle.js:1:32702)

The solution suggested at various places has been to change the version of ipywidgets, as there are some compatibility issues. My ipywidgets is 7.6.5 and I tried changing it to 7.7.5, 7.7.2 and a couple of more, but I keep getting the Javascript error.
The following are my Jupyter core packages' versions:
IPython          : 8.20.0
ipykernel        : 6.28.0
ipywidgets       : 7.6.5
jupyter_client   : 8.6.0
jupyter_core     : 5.5.0
jupyter_server   : 2.10.0
jupyterlab       : 4.0.11
nbclient         : 0.8.0
nbconvert        : 7.10.0
nbformat         : 5.9.2
notebook         : 7.0.8
qtconsole        : 5.4.2
traitlets        : 5.7.1

Where am I making a mistake? Thanks.

The problem was solved by pip install ipywidgets==8.0.4

Many thanks for saying what helped. Wow, that is a bit odd that Anaconda would be giving you that old of ipywidgets, especially for use in conjunction with Jupyter Notebook 7+. From my cursory looking into it, that ipywidgets version if 2 years and 8 months old, at least. One minor concern, I would have suggested based on here first trying conda install conda-forge::ipywidgets. (You could modify that to specify a version if preferred.) The reason being is that when installed Anaconda/conda, that became your primary package manager by choice. ..

 Mixing and matching conda and pip is a recipe for non-robust and nonportable environments. Admittedly you have to choose to use it for cases where there's no conda recipe. And a command like you ran with pip install can often get you past a hurdle. Ideally, though stick with Anaconda/conda to install things as much as you can going forward. Oh wait, you have way more rep than me; you probably know all that and were just troubleshooting, which is definitely one place it can help to mix. Never mind. (But maybe my cautions will help someone else.)

Many thanks. Your inputs were helpful from the post I referred to and the cue I got from it helped me get past the issue. Well, for some reasons, we have to use pip at our work place, as conda doesn't work. By at my personal work station, I do prefer conda. Your insights were quite helpful, as well as the hint you provided with MyBinder. Thanks.
